# Music metadata missing after mklink

Tags: windows-10, nas, windows-media-player, mklink

I have successfully linked my NAS music folder to my Windows Music Library but there is a problem with the metadata within the symbolic linked folder. I did this with `MKLINK`

In the original folder on the NAS, the file contains the metadata

[image: file on NAS]

However, in the symbolic linked folder I get the below

[image: linked file]

The problem this causes is that in Windows Media Player none of the proper artist, genre, rating, etc information is available and then I am unable to sync to portable devices.

This was all working previously but I just replaced my NAS and with the new link it is no longer working. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you check if the symbolic linked folder is indexed by Windows? To view/modify the list of indexed locations, press `Win+R`, type `control.exe srchadmin.dll`, and press Enter. If the folder isn't in the list, you can add it by clicking `Modify`.

Comment: @TimDeBaets what's strange is when I do as you mention it doesn't show and doesn't allow me to add the folder (it doesn't appear in the list of folders on the computer under modify menu).

Comment: Have you already changed the location of the Music library to the new folder? If not, you can do this by right-clicking the `Music` library in Explorer, selecting `Properties`, and heading to the `Location` tab. If that doesn't help, please right-click the symbolic folder, select `Always available offline`, and try adding it as an indexed location again.